# Getting shadows/outlines/shapes of icons

Tags: android, icons, shapes, homescreen, outline

I was wondering if it is possible to get shadows/shapes of icons on home screen in android? I know when you add some custom icon to your homescreen and then move it around you get outlines of that icon. ( at least in samsungs TouchWiz 4+ and API 11+ ). So is there a way to obtain shapes and locations of icons on homescreen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short sample of what you could do:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView view = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_outline));
        view.setImageBitmap(createOutline(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        view.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
    }

    private Bitmap createOutline(Bitmap src) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, Blur.OUTER));
        return src.extractAlpha(p, null);
    }
}
```

Is that what you had in mind? (Note that if you have to align the blurred image with the original you should pass an int array of length two to extractAlpha. The array will contain the offsets you should use to align the outline.)

Comment: Yes but this will only work for my own applications icon, but I want to be able to get outlines of other applications too that are on homescreen, even if they are not developed my be.

Comment: Look at the PackageManager, there are several methods to load data from other applications, for example icons. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon(java.lang.String)) may be what you want. Render the drawable to a bitmap and use the method above.

Comment: is there a way also to get only icons of those apps that currently have shortcuts on homescreen?

Comment: As far as I know there is no public way to query the shortcuts, but you can query which apps or rather activities are available in the app tray using the package manager. Just look for matching intent filters.