# How to create Android ICS drag'n'drop shadow effect?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, shadow, outline

I would like to create icon shadow/outline effect in my app, as presented on [Google's design guidelines page](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html).
The effect I would like to reach:

[image: Example]

Has anyone noticed the part of code which dynamically creates a mask, and then creates a outline like this above?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "shadow", but more like an "outline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found a solution. Previously the search engine didn't return any satisfying results (because I typed 'shadow', not 'outline'), and I made duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237453/getting-shadows-outlines-shapes-of-icons).